# URL with hyphen can not open with Android browser

Tags: android, url, browser, dns, rfc3986

I've met a very strange problem. URL such as `http://wei-.x.yupoo.com`

can be opened with Windows PC, macOS, iOS browser, but not with Android browser, it reports DNS error.

Can any one help me to figure out why? I've checked RFC7320 and RFC3986, in RFC3986 sec 3.1

> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a
>   letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, plus
>   ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-").  Although schemes are case-
>   insensitive, the canonical form is lowercase and documents that
>   specify schemes must do so with lowercase letters.  An implementation 
>   should accept uppercase letters as equivalent to lowercase in scheme
>   names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as well as "http") for the sake of
>   robustness but should only produce lowercase scheme names for
>   consistency.

Seems this url should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Chrome in Android. I try it in my one plus three and it can be opened

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the hyphen with `%E2%80%93`

example: `http://wei%E2%80%93.x.yupoo.com`